# Is it possible to combine contentclass terms in a Rest call?

Tags: search, rest, ajax, sharepoint-on-prem, query-string

SharePoint onPremise - 2013. I'm attempting to use the following string, and get errors.

`'contentclass:"STS_Web" OR contentclass:"STS_List_DocumentLibrary"';`

It works perfectly if I specify a single contentclass.

Comment: You don't need the double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your scenario and seems working fine with below syntax.

```
<<site url>>/_api/search/query?querytext='(contentclass="STS_Web" OR contentclass="STS_List_DocumentLibrary")'
```

See if this works for you

Comment: onPrem or O365?

Comment: O365 Environment

Comment: That might be it - I'm using an onPrem system. 2013.

Comment: This works fine for me in Office 365. The double quotes are optional.

Comment: I'm running the query in an onPrem environment. It fails. It also fails with "=". I have to use the ":" character. (Contains rather than equal to).